# How to get the position from a View?

Tags: android

How do I get the position from this View when I cannot declare a global variable here?
The method GetView() has a variable named position, but I can do nothing with that because is manipulated in both  getView() and onClickListener().
This means that as each row of my list is created, I lose the reference to the previous Buttons in favor of the new one.
When any Button is clicked and the listener evoked, my logic will only happen for the last row created with getView(), not necessarily the clicked row.

```
    @Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    ToggleButton fav = (ToggleButton) view;
    if(!Checked[pos]) {
        Toast.makeText(customView.getContext(),"ON in Posicion: "+pos,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        fav.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(customView.getContext(), R.drawable.like));
        Checked[pos]=true;
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(customView.getContext(),"OFF in Posicion: "+pos,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        fav.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(customView.getContext(), R.drawable.dislike));
        Checked[pos] = false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 approaches to your problem.

1. In the `Adapter` class while binding the data to the view. Use the `View#setTag()` method and pass the position like `toggleButton.setTag(position)` and when receiving the View in `onClick()` method you can easily fetch the positon using `toggleButton.getTag()`
2. In second approach, create a interface and pass it to your adapter and in getView of your Adapter class add a listener on toggleButton while binding data to view and whenever user clicks a ToggleButton, just call the method of the interface you have just passed.

Snippet be like:

```
   public interface IToggleButtonListener{
void onToggleButtonClicked(ToggleButton button, int position);
}
```

Activity be like:

```
      public class MainActivity extends Activity implements IToggleButtonListener{

@Override
void onCreate(Bundle saveInstance){
Adapter adapter = new Adapter(this, this//toggleListener);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

    @Override
    void onToggleButtonClicked(ToggleButton button, int position){
//Your code goes here
    }
        }
```

Adapter class be like:

```
public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter{

private IToggleButtonListener mListener ;
public Adapter(Activity activity, IToggleButtonListener listener){
mListener = listener;
}
....
....

@Override
public View getView(int pos){

//..Bind your data to view
toggleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
void onClicke(View view){
if(mListener !=null){
mListener.onToggleButtonClicked(view,pos);
}
}
}
);
}
}
```

Sorry for formatting.

Thanks